# Unable to initialize spark context using java

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

i am trying a simple work count program using spark , but its fails when i try to initialize spark context.
Below is my code

```
conf = new SparkConf(true).
                setAppName("WordCount").
                setMaster("spark://192.168.0.104:7077");

        sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```

Now few things i wanted to clarify  i am using Spark version 2.1.1 , my java code is on windows  10 and my server is running on VM box.
I have disabled firewall in VM and can access URL http://192.168.0.104:8080/ from windows.

However i am getting below stacktrace when running the code

```
17/08/06 18:44:15 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://192.168.0.103:4040
17/08/06 18:44:15 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://192.168.0.104:7077...
17/08/06 18:44:15 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /192.168.0.104:7077 after 41 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
17/08/06 18:44:15 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master 192.168.0.104:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
```

Can some one help ?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but for those running into this now: This can be caused by the maven version used for Spark Core or Spark SQL not being compatible with the Spark version being used on the server. At this moment Spark 2.4.4 appears to be compatible with the following Maven setup:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Incompatibility issues can be diagnosed by viewing the Spark Master node logs. They should mention something along the lines of `spark local class incompatible stream classdesc serialversionuid`

I hope this is still of some use to some!

Answer (score -1):

You need to import some Spark classes into your program. Add the following lines:

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("WordCount").setMaster("local");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```